# Create a table from row values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that looks like this,

| Scenario 1A | Scenario 2 | Scenario 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Function 1 | Function 1 | Function 2 |
| Function 2 | Function 3 |  |
| Function 3 |  |  |

I want a table that lists the scenarios by the functions so

| Function 1 | Function 2 | Function 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scenario 1A | Scenario 1A | Scenario 1A |
| Scenario 2 | Scenario 3 | Scenario 2 |

I'm using Office 365.

Is there any way to achieve this automatically? I've been messing around for an hour with various combinations of INDEX, FILTER, etc., and can't figure it out.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Power Query to translate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Posting more simpler and easy ways, when using `MS365` --> `Fill Right` Approach!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=UNIQUE(TOROW(A2:C4,1),1)
```

---

&

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd> --> Fill Right!

```
=SORT(TOCOL(IFS(E$1=$A$2:$C$4,$A$1:$C$1),3))
```

---

The above solution needs to fill right, while the solution posted below are dynamic. This can be accomplished by using **`Excel Formulas`** as well as using `POWER QUERY`, but using `POWER QUERY` will be most recommended as far i think.

Using **`Excel Formulas`** applicable to `MS365` exclusively.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(A2:C4<>"",A1:C1),3),TOCOL(A2:C4,1)),
     φ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     δ, TOROW(UNIQUE(φ)),
     VSTACK(δ,DROP(REDUCE("",δ, LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(TAKE(α,,1),φ=y)))),,1)))
```

---

- Variable `α` --> Helps to stack the data vertically and merging the each groups together.
- Variable `φ` --> Extracting the `Function` Group.
- Variable `δ` --> Getting Unique & Aligning Horizontally the `Function` Group
- Lastly, using `REDUCE()` function to loop over each unique function group to return the respective scenarios row wise.

---

Or Using `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards Windows and MAC.

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Value"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Attribute=text, Value=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Attribute", "Value", "Index"}, {"Attribute", "Value", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Value]), "Value", "Attribute"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Another alternative method using <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, A2:C4,
     φ, UNIQUE(TOROW(α,1),1),
     VSTACK(φ, MAKEARRAY(MAX(MAP(φ,LAMBDA(s,SUM(--(α=s))))),3,LAMBDA(r,c,
     INDEX(TOCOL(IF(INDEX(UNIQUE(TOROW(α,1),1),,c)=α,A1:C1,z),3),r,)))))
```

---

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I thought they would be a way with PQ.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution on the screenshot.
[image: Scenarios]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Very smart.